# flyway schema history table name

Tags: flyway

We've been using flyway for schema migrations, versions 4.x/5.x - the table is named **schema_version**.  Now we are looking to move to latest version, 7.x.  I've seen some information that states the new table name has changed to **flyway_schema_history**, but then I just saw this where the table name looks to be named **flyway_history_schema** (https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/migrations#schema-history-table).

Can anyone who uses flyway confirm the schema history table name?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default name for the table is indeed **flyway_schema_history**

The part of the documentation you linked to is referring to the situation when Flyway is not allowed to create new schemas by its configuration, and you need to manually create a schema for that table to live in. "flyway_history_schema" is a suggested name for the **schema**, not the table.

Answer (score 0):

So we encountered this and we simply just updated our configuration such as this example, Java flyway 7.15.0

```java
import org.flywaydb.core.Flyway;

final Flyway flyway =
        Flyway.configure()
            .locations(
                Optional.ofNullable(locations)
                    .filter(col -> !col.isEmpty())
                    .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
                    .toArray(new String[0]))
            .dataSource(this.dataSource)
                .table("schema_version")
            .load();
```

Comment: Where did you find it?

Comment: Can you expound on your question ? Like where did we find the table name?

Comment: Sorry. I was wondering where you found this block code. I thought it was some flyway cli configuration.

Comment: Based off the https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/api-java-184127629.html documentation